# not able to get the data in req.user in the user controller which i have implemented in the user isloggedIn middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt, middleware

i cannot access my req.user in usercontroller , which i have implemented in the usermiddleware

i am not able to store data in req.user and also not able to get data using req.user from middleware to my controller

**usercontroller:**

```
exports.getLoggedInUserDetails = BigPromise(async (req, res, next) => {
   
    const user = await User.findById(req.user.id)
    console.log(user)
    res.status(200).json({
        success:true,
        user
    })
  });
```

**usermiddleware:**

```
const User = require('../models/user')
const BigPromise = require("../middleware/bigPromise");
const CustomError = require("../utils/customError");
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')

exports.isLoggedIn = BigPromise(async(req,res,next)=>{
    const token = req.cookies.token 
    if (!token) {
        return next(new CustomError("Login first to access this page", 401));
    }

    //if token is present then:
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token , process.env.JWT_SECRET) 
    console.log(decoded)
    req.user = User.findById(decoded.id)  

    next();

})
```

```
**route**


router.route("/userdashboard").get(isLoggedIn, getLoggedInUserDetails);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store your user login in a session for node to remember that a user has signed in.

You can use express-session for this.